# System.InvalidOperationException when trying to execute SqlDataReader

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql

I would like to post my SQL results into a textlist in VB.net, I am selecting from 2 fields, `UserName` & `Passwords`

My query is:

```
USE fasttest2008;

SELECT [username],
       [password]
FROM   users;
```

I want it to post into tb_user & tb_pass

I have looked at another post on this site and managed to nearly get it, i feel that I am missing just one thing.

I am aware this code only posts the results into one field atm.

```
Dim sConnString As String = "Data Source=.\scuser;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim sText As String = String.Empty

        Using cn As New SqlConnection(sConnString)
            cn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("use testdb select [username], [password] from users")
            Dim r As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If Not r.HasRows Then Exit Sub

            Do While r.Read()
                sText = sText & ";" & r.GetString(0)
            Loop

            cn.Close()
        End Using

        lb_user.Text = sText
```

Comment: `sText =  r.GetString(0) & " - " & r.GetString(1)`  Passwords should not be stored as plaintext

Comment: @Plutonix The error I get is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: on which line?  is that the correct connection string?

Comment: Cause you didn't associate the cn to cmd..

Comment: Ah yes.  Add the connection object to the Command constructor:  I am not sure it will like the `USE` directive in the query, seems like that should be in the conn str

Comment: @User2012384 the cn = sconnstring which is the correct connection string.

Comment: @Plutonix could you show me what you mean sorry?

Comment: @SamCramphorn Yes, your connectionstring is correct, but you haven't assigned that connectionstring to the sql command, please have a look at my answer, see if that helps

Comment: Note that your title has nothing to do with a connection problem, the post doesnt mention an error and asks about something completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try modify the Connection to this:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("use testdb select [username], [password] from users", cn);
```

You have to associate the cn to cmd

As in the comment, you said the query isn't returning anything, so try removing the `use testdb`, and try running it in the Database server, see if it returns anything

Comment: Edit: Thanks,

| This now goes through, however it doesn't return my results.

Comment: I used a breakpoint and it was contained in sText so I know it is their.

Comment: So you will have to find out when the sText is cleared